# How can I id two videos on a webpage

Tags: html, html5-video

Can I ask if I have two videos how is the code correct? I cannot find info on it. All code works in codepen but the validator error is that I cannot obviously use **second** as an id for my vimeo video. I have **main id** for the youtube video but I get I cannot reuse **main id** again. I know there is a solution to change the word **second** but were do I find it?  Can I ask how I can code this correct? 


<**second id**=my-vimeo  class='vimeo-first'>

Comment: Without a [mcve] it is difficult to help you in a constructive way please read [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The simplest solution to the question you wrote is: Youtube video has `id="vid1"` and then Vimeo video has `id="vid2"`. Then your code knows `vid1` means youtube and the other is Vimeo. What is **the real problem**?